# Convert string to json with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am using angular formly to generate some forms. I'm retrieving the form definition from my database, which is multiple json objects. In javascript how to I convert (for example) the following string into an array of objects?

```
"{"template": "<h2>MAIN HEADING.</h2>"
},
{
    "template": "<h4>sub heading.</h4>"
}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap it in `[]` so it becomes a JSON array, and then parse it:

```
var result = JSON.parse( '[' + str + ']' );
```